# Bind List of List of Object to DataGrid Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding, datagrid

It may sound weird but first read why I am trying to do that.

I read the name of the columns that I want to show on grid from an xml file, run a query only for those column and construct an object. I do not know the names of classes or their properties (I read them from xml file), so I cant declare them. So I am left with an option to declare a class as following for each column that I read from db.

```
public class LabelValueTypeGroup
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is one column. So a row would be

```
List<LabelValueTypeGroup> or ObservableCollection<LabelValueTypeGroup>
```

and then the whole table would be

```
List<List<LabelValueTypeGroup>> or ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<LabelValueTypeGroup>>
```

Obviously, when I tried binding it with a grid, it first showed me a table of Lengths of the InnerLists like this

```
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
```

And on binding it with first index of the list it shows

```
Label   Value    Type    
ID      435      System.Decimal
Name    John     System.String
Phone   3453113  System.String
Email   j@j.com  System.String
```

Is there any way that I could bind it with the grid in a way that it takes the inside list as columns and outside list as rows? I mean I realize that it would not be a straightforward bind, but as I am new to silverlight, any help would worth a lot to me.

Comment: Make life easier using a System.Data.DataTable or System.Data.DataSet, and fill its internal table. There is lot of docu around that explain binding wpf / Silverlight (e.g a DataGrid) to a DataSet.

Comment: Both not available in Silverlight.

Comment: I learnded something. You can treat each row like a viewmodel, like you already wrote: ObservableCollection<LabelValueTypeGroup>, and set it as a DataGrid's ItemsSource. No nested List declaration needed fo r that.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight, you can bind a DataGrid to `Dictionary<string, object>` type rows.  This will be the easiest route for you to go:

- parse the XML file
- create an `IList<Dictionary<string, object>>` and populate it with the label/value pairs from the XML file
- add a `DataGridTextColumn` to the DataGrid for each distinct column your "LabelValueTypeGroup" set

So you'll have a DataGrid like this:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

The "Items" property will be like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>> Items { get; private set; }
```

When you have parsed the XML file, then populate the "Items" collection and the grid's "Columns" set.  Note that the syntax for binding to dictionary entries is `Binding Path=[key]`.  So the populate-table code should look something like this:

```
public void FillTable(List<List<LabelValueTypeGroup>> rows)
{
    var columnSet = rows.SelectMany(row => row.Select(col => col.Label)).Distinct();

    foreach (var columnLabel in columnSet)
    {
        columnSet.Add(columnLabel);
        var gridColumn = new DataGridTextColumn 
        { 
            Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", columnLabel)),
            Header = columnLabel,
        };
        grid.Columns.Add(gridColumn);
    }

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        var item = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var col in row)
        {
            item[col.Label] = col.Value;
        }
        Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Of course you might want to add some code to convert the "Value" from a string to whatever type is specified in the "LabelValueTypeGroup" record.

---

I just wanted to note for completeness' sake, that there is an alternative to the above approach (probably overkill for your case).  Silverlight does supports runtime typing, using [`ICustomTypeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/system.reflection.icustomtypeprovider(v=vs.95).aspx).  It is more difficult to use than the WPF DataTable, though -- basically you have to inherit `System.Type` and `System.Property`.  This takes some effort and trial-and-error to get running, but once set up correctly a custom type will work seamlessly with the Silverlight DataGrid.  Again though, I would recommend the above approach of manually populating the DataGrid, rather than this custom-typing approach, for your scenario.

Comment: I am sorry for replying so late. In viewmodel, I wont be able to access the grid by its name **"grid"**.